# Python: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - How to add file to the right directory

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse

I'm new to python! Seen many issues related to this problem but can't find the right way of doing it.
I want to import a picture and change it.

My code is:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import os

root_dir= os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(r'C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Practice Python CS50 2019\images\Mario.png'))
before = Image.open('Mario.png')
after=before.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
after.save("MarioBLUR.png")
```

The error I'm getting is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Practice Python CS50 2019\src\Class 6\blur.py", line 5, in 
before = Image.open('Mario.png')
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2809, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Mario.png'

My windows location for this picture is: C:\Users\User\Downloads\Mario.png
My eclipse location is: C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Practice Python\images\Mario.png

How to add this picture to the right directory to make sure I won't have this issue anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You only need the directory path and not the filename in `os.path.dirname`, for example:

```
root_dir= os.path.dirname('C:/Users/User/eclipse-workspace/Practice Python CS50 2019/images/')
before = Image.open(root_dir + 'Mario.png')
```

should work fine